# Problema con flutter _CastError (type 'Time' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, datetime, cast

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora que quiero importar una función de un archivo distinto pero en distinta carpeta (el archivo se encuentro en `lib\components`), me arroja el siguiente error:`_CastError (type 'Time' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast)`

[GitHub](https://github.com/0w4n/HubApp/blob/main/lib/main.dart#:%7E:text=DateTime%20today%20%3D%20Tiempo()%3B).

El problema es que no encuentro donde esta mi error, ya que aparece al poner el compilador en marcha...

El código se encuentra en esta manera:

```
DateTime today = Tiempo() as DateTime;
```

Pero también he intentado:

```
DateTime today = Tiempo();
```

`Tiempo()` sale de aquí:

```
class Tiempo {
   late DateTime today = DateTime.now();
}
```

Este se encuentra en `time.dart`, y la importo `import 'components/time.dart';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es correcto, Tu clase `Tiempo` no es un subtipo de `DateTime`, no necesitas ni un cast para obtener el atributo `today` del objeto tiempo.

Tendría que ser así:

```dart
DateTime today = Tiempo().today;
```

Estas creando una instancia de `Tiempo` y estás obteniendo el atributo que declaraste como `today`.